# AngularJs: assignment data to variable from multidimensional json

Tags: angularjs

I have multidimensional json:

```
{"cat":
        {"total":12,"per_page":3,"current_page":1,"last_page":4,"from":1,"to":3,
         "data":[{"id":1,"emlakKategori":"a"},{"id":2,"emlakKategori":"b"},{"id":3,"emlakKategori":"c"}]}}
```

And i am reaching to data via ng-repeat like this:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="kat in kategoriList.cat.data">
        <td>{{ kat.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ kat.emlakKategori }}</td>
```

My service is:

```
   app.factory('KategoriData',['$resource', 'api.config', function($resource, config) {
return $resource(config.apiBasePath + 'kategori',{}, {
    query: {
        isArray: false,
        method: 'GET'
    }
});
```

And my controller:

```
kategori.controller('KategoriListCtrl',['$scope', 'KategoriData', function($scope, KategoriData) {
    $scope.kategoriList = KategoriData.query();
```

}

I wonder how can i assign data to variable inside controller and reach it in view with directly kategoriList instead of kategoriList.cat.data

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the assignment in your controller in the success callback of your query.

```
kategori.controller('KategoriListCtrl',['$scope', 'KategoriData', function($scope, KategoriData) {
    KategoriData.query({},
         function(data){
             $scope.kategoriList = data.cat.data;
         });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your example is not valid anymore due to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577) (since  **v1.2.0-rc.3** )

`deprecate promise unwrapping` means that you can not bind a scope value to a promise and when the promise will be resolved a $digest will automatically unwrap it.

You should use a callback:

```
kategori.controller('KategoriListCtrl',['$scope', 'KategoriData', function($scope, KategoriData) {
  KategoriData.query({}, function(data){
    $scope.kategoriList.cat.data = data;
  })
}
```